# Delphi 10 Seattle Database connection (DB2)

Tags: delphi, db2, delphi-10-seattle, firedac

I'm Migrating my Delphi 2006 application to Delphi 10 Seattle. I have used TDatabase, TQuery and TUpdateSQL components in my application. When I replace these components with TFDConnection, TFDQuery and TFDUpdatesQL. I'm getting error SQL3008IN.. Please let me know how to migrate DB components in Delphi 10 Seattle. Im using DB2 database.

Answer (score 0):

That error, `SQL30081N` (note it's a `1`, and not an `I` at the end), indicates some sort of network communication error. Have a look at [this article](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21164785) (or [this one](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql30081n.html)) to see what the sub-code you are getting means.

Comment: Hi Bhamby, I'm able to connect DB2 database from my old application. I'm not sure how to establish connection in TFDconnection component. can you please help me on this. thanks.